# How can I clear() the inner vector in a type of vector<pair<int,vector> >?

Tags: c++, vector

I have declared a vector pair of int and vector as `vector<pair<int,vector<int> > v(10)` . Now I want to use clear function as `v[i].clear()` and expecting that it will clear the row `v[i]`. But the compiler throws an error. Please help me to use clear() function properly to clear a particular row in such vector declaration or suggest me a different way of doing so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to wipe out the i'th row, then you want erase:

```
v.erase(v.begin() + i);
```

In your example, this would reduce the size of your vector by one, leaving only 9 elements remaining.

On the other hand, if you want to re-initialize the i'th row, so that it contains the same thing that it did when you first created the vector to have 10 elements in it, then you want:

```
v[i] = pair<int, vector<int> >();
```

--or--

```
v[i].first = 0;
v[i].second.clear();
```

Comment: ...yeah that's what i exactly want ...but i wonder that `v[i].second.clear()` will do the same thing ..correct me if i am wrong :/

Comment: `vector::erase` takes an iterator not an index, so this code won't work.

Comment: It almost does the same thing; v[i].second.clear() won't clear out v[i].first.

Answer (score 0):

Your outer `std::vector` contains `std::pair`s and `clear` is a method on `std::vector` not `std::pair`. It looks like you may mean this:

```
v[i].second.clear();
```

If you'd like to remove the entire *i*th element from the vector, then that is a different question than what you asked. Instead you can remove it this way:

```
v.erase(v.begin() + i);
```

If you want to fully reset the *i*th element, then you should default construct the value like this:

```
v[i] = pair<int, vector<int> >();
```

or like this:

```
v[i] = std::make_pair(0, std::vector<int>());
```

Also, note that calling `clear` does not actually free up the "reserved" space inside the vector, so if your vector is really large and you want to *truly* get rid of all the memory, then you'll need to assign an empty (default constructed) vector. Alternatively, you can call use the swap-with-empty idiom:

```
v[i].second.swap(std::vector<int>());
```

Comment: No i just want to initialize the ith row as in the beginning

Comment: `v.erase[&v[i]]` won't compile.  `v.erase(&v[i])` might compile but is not guaranteed to: `vector<T>::iterator` is NOT necessarily `T*`.